# After authentication directed to developer sandbox and not to embedded signing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docusignapi

I am using a code example for Authorization Code Grant with DocuSign, and the authentication seems to work okay, but the code never reaches the actual creation of an envelope for signage. After authentication I get directed to the developer sandbox, am assuming this not correct because it should send me to Eg001EmbeddedSigning Controller. Am I missing something?

I have tried adding the integrator key and secret which I do have. I've tried navigating to Eg001EmbeddingSigning/Create from my localhost and it cannot find the page.

View I expect to occur after authentication:

```
@model DocuSign.Managers.ViewModels.SigningViewModel

<h4>DocuSign Embedded Signing Ceremony</h4>
<p>This example sends an envelope, and then uses an embedded signing ceremony for the first signer.</p>
<p>
    Embedded signing provides a smoother user experience for the signer: the DocuSign signing ceremony is initiated from
    your website.
</p>
@if (ViewBag.showDoc == true)
{
    <p><a target='_blank' href='@ViewBag.documentation'>Documentation</a> about this example.</p>
}

<form class="eg" action="" method="post" data-busy="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="signerEmail">Signer Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="signerEmail" name="signerEmail"
               aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="pat@example.com" required
               value="@ViewBag.Locals.DsConfig.SignerEmail">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="signerName">Signer Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="signerName" placeholder="Pat Johnson" name="signerName"
               value="@ViewBag.Locals.DsConfig.SignerName" required>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="@ViewBag.csrfToken">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Index Page:

```
@{
    var locals = ViewData["locals"] as Locals;//ViewBag.Locals;
    bool showDoc;
    Boolean.TryParse(ViewData["showDoc"].ToString(), out showDoc);//ViewBag.ShowDoc;
}
@if (locals.User == null)
{
    <!-- IF not signed in -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome!</h1>
        <p class="Xlead">
           DocuSign with
            OAuth Authorization Code Grant.
        </p>
    </div>
}

<div id="index-page">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>This launcher both demonstrates use of the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow and includes multiple usage examples for the DocuSign eSignature REST API.</p>

    @if (ViewBag.showDoc)
    {
        <p><a target='_blank' href='@ViewBag.documentation'>Documentation</a> on using OAuth Authorization Code Grant from a C# .NET Core MVC application.</p>
    }

    <h2>Basic Examples</h2>

    <h4 id="example001">1. <a href="eg001">Embedded Signing Ceremony</a></h4>
    <p>
        This example sends an envelope, and then uses an embedded signing ceremony for the first signer.
        With embedded signing, the DocuSign signing ceremony is initiated from your website.
    </p>
```

DocuSign Controller:

```
namespace DocuSign.Controllers
{

    [Route("ds/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
        }

        public IActionResult MustAuthenticate()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IActionResult> logout()
        {
            await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext);
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
    }
```

Eg001EmbeddedSigningController:

```
namespace DocuSign.Views
{
    [Route("eg001")]
    public class Eg001EmbeddedSigningController : EgController
    {
        private string dsPingUrl;
        private string signerClientId = "1000";
        private string dsReturnUrl;

        private readonly DocuSignManager _docuSignManager;

        public Eg001EmbeddedSigningController(DSConfiguration config, IRequestItemsService requestItemsService, DocuSignManager docuSignManager)
            : base(config, requestItemsService)
        {            
            dsPingUrl = config.AppUrl + "/";
            dsReturnUrl = config.AppUrl + "/dsReturn";           
            ViewBag.title = "Embedded Signing Ceremony";
            _docuSignManager = docuSignManager;
        }

        // ***DS.snippet.0.start
        private string DoWork(string signerEmail, string signerName,
            string accessToken, string basePath, string accountId)
        {
            // Data for this method
            // signerEmail 
            // signerName
            // accessToken
            // basePath
            // accountId

            // dsPingUrl -- class global
            // signerClientId -- class global
            // dsReturnUrl -- class global

            // Step 1. Create the envelope definition
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName);

            // Step 2. Call DocuSign to create the envelope                   
            var config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
            config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
            EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
            string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;

            // Save for future use within the example launcher
            RequestItemsService.EnvelopeId = envelopeId;

            // Step 3. create the recipient view, the Signing Ceremony
            RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = MakeRecipientViewRequest(signerEmail, signerName);
            // call the CreateRecipientView API
            ViewUrl results1 = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);

            // Step 4. Redirect the user to the Signing Ceremony
            // Don't use an iFrame!
            // State can be stored/recovered using the framework's session or a
            // query parameter on the returnUrl (see the makeRecipientViewRequest method)
            string redirectUrl = results1.Url;
            return redirectUrl;
        }

        private RecipientViewRequest MakeRecipientViewRequest(string signerEmail, string signerName)
        {
            // Data for this method
            // signerEmail 
            // signerName
            // dsPingUrl -- class global
            // signerClientId -- class global
            // dsReturnUrl -- class global


            RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest();
            // Set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
            // should typically be a callback route somewhere in your app.
            // The query parameter is included as an example of how
            // to save/recover state information during the redirect to
            // the DocuSign signing ceremony. It's usually better to use
            // the session mechanism of your web framework. Query parameters
            // can be changed/spoofed very easily.
            viewRequest.ReturnUrl = dsReturnUrl + "?state=123";

            // How has your app authenticated the user? In addition to your app's
            // authentication, you can include authenticate steps from DocuSign.
            // Eg, SMS authentication
            viewRequest.AuthenticationMethod = "none";




            // Recipient information must match embedded recipient info
            // we used to create the envelope.
            viewRequest.Email = signerEmail;
            viewRequest.UserName = signerName;
            viewRequest.ClientUserId = signerClientId;

            // DocuSign recommends that you redirect to DocuSign for the
            // Signing Ceremony. There are multiple ways to save state.
            // To maintain your application's session, use the pingUrl
            // parameter. It causes the DocuSign Signing Ceremony web page
            // (not the DocuSign server) to send pings via AJAX to your
            // app,
            viewRequest.PingFrequency = "600"; // seconds
                                               // NOTE: The pings will only be sent if the pingUrl is an https address
            viewRequest.PingUrl = dsPingUrl; // optional setting

            return viewRequest;
        }

        private EnvelopeDefinition MakeEnvelope(string signerEmail, string signerName)
        {
            // Data for this method
            // signerEmail 
            // signerName
            // signerClientId -- class global
            // Config.docPdf


            //byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Config.docPdf);

            byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\username\\source\\repos\\DocuSign\\DocuSign\\Test 2.pdf");

            EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envelopeDefinition.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document";
            Document doc1 = new Document();

            String doc1b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

            doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64;
            doc1.Name = "Lorem Ipsum"; // can be different from actual file name
            doc1.FileExtension = "pdf";
            doc1.DocumentId = "3";

            // The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
            envelopeDefinition.Documents = new List<Document> { doc1 };

            var user = _docuSignManager.GetUserInfo();

            // Create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
            // We set the clientUserId to enable embedded signing for the recipient
            // We're setting the parameters via the object creation
            Signer signer1 = new Signer {
                Email = user.Email,
                Name = user.UserName,
                ClientUserId = signerClientId,
                RecipientId = "1"
            };

            var position = _docuSignManager.GetPositionData(); //TODO Add to get by username.

            //Get the field location.
            //var field =_docuSignManager.GetField();

            var fieldInfo = _docuSignManager.GetFieldByPosition(position);



            // Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
            // We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
            //
            // The DocuSign platform seaches throughout your envelope's
            // documents for matching anchor strings.
            SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
            {
                DocumentId = "1",
                PageNumber = fieldInfo.PageNumber.ToString(),
                RecipientId = "1",
                TabLabel = position.PositionName,
                XPosition = fieldInfo.XOffset.ToString(),
                YPosition = fieldInfo.YOffset.ToString()
            };
            // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
            Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 }
            };
            signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;

            // Add the recipient to the envelope object
            Recipients recipients = new Recipients
            {
                Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 }
            };
            envelopeDefinition.Recipients = recipients;

            // Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
            // To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
            envelopeDefinition.Status = "sent";

            return envelopeDefinition;
        }
        // ***DS.snippet.0.end


        public override string EgName => "eg001";

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(SigningViewModel model)
        {
            // Data for this method
            // signerEmail 
            // signerName
            // dsPingUrl -- class global
            // signerClientId -- class global
            // dsReturnUrl -- class global
            string accessToken = RequestItemsService.User.AccessToken;
            string basePath = RequestItemsService.Session.BasePath + "/restapi";
            string accountId = RequestItemsService.Session.AccountId;

            // Check the token with minimal buffer time.
            bool tokenOk = CheckToken(3);
            if (!tokenOk)
            {
                // We could store the parameters of the requested operation 
                // so it could be restarted automatically.
                // But since it should be rare to have a token issue here,
                // we'll make the user re-enter the form data after 
                // authentication.
                RequestItemsService.EgName = EgName;
                return Redirect("/ds/mustAuthenticate");
            }

            string redirectUrl = DoWork(model.Email, model.Name, accessToken, basePath, accountId);
            // Redirect the user to the Signing Ceremony
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect after authentication to get sent to the document for signing within the browser.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to your question! PLEASE upvote all useful answers you see, including those to others' questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different "returns" involved here.

1. During the OAuth flow: After the user authenticates (and consents to using your app, a one time process), the DocuSign authentication server should redirect to your app's OAuth url. Your code (or your framework's code) should then exchange the authorization code provided as a query parameter for an access token.

**I think this is your issue.**

Check that you have the `redirect uri` set up in the DocuSign Admin tool for your integration key.

**Added:** Set the redirect URI *for your application's Integration Key* from the Admin tool, using the API and Keys screen. (See the navigation screenshot, below.)

[image]

**Important:** You must set the Redirect URI to be exactly the same as what your application uses. Eg, `http://localhost:8080/ds/callback` You can use http or https. localhost is fine.

Also check what redirect uri is being used when your app starts the oauth process with DocuSign. (Visible on the url sent to DocuSign to start OAuth)

See the [Prerequisites section of the readme](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core#prerequisites) for the return URI setting.

The signing ceremony "return"--

2. After you obtain the access token and create the envelope, you use the recipient view API method to obtain a URL for the signing ceremony. Here, you provide your return url which is used after the user completes the signing ceremony.

To debug this, start by [downloading the request logs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) from DocuSign to assure that you're specifying the return url as you expect.

Comment: On the login, it says "There are no redirect URIs registered with DocuSign", so I am guessing this is the problem you mentioned. Can I use localhost for the redirect URI, or do I need make one up?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Redirect URIs as am not sure how to setup a custom one in my app if I need to but it looks like I can use http://localhost:8080/ds/callback according to the readme.

Comment: I have requested the the Redirect URI (localhost:8080/ds/callback) to be added, but now I get "The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign".

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to add the `http://` localhost is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to gather additional information:

- Fiddler logs can show the various redirects and which urls are called
- DocuSign API logs can show any APIs being called and any errors
- Using VS Debugger, put a breakpoint inside MakeRecipientViewRequest(). see
  if you get there, and if it follows to completion and what url is coming back from API. Try this url yourself to see if it works.